# How can -Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments warning be turned off with Clang?

Tags: clang, warnings, suppress-warnings

**Context**

I read [Clang's "Controlling Diagnostics via Pragmas"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#id22) section about turning off particular warnings. It works well in general for all warnings except for *-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments*.

The code is:

MyHeader.hpp

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments"

#import "header generating -Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments warning"

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

**Problem**

Clang generates *-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments* warnings while compiling translation units importing MyHeader.hpp.

**Env**

Clang Version: 
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.51) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix

OS: Mac OS X 10.9.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be working in Xcode 6.4 (6E35b). The pragma suppresses the warning now.

I have `-Weverything` in build settings. Without the diagnostic ignore I definitely get the warning:

> Token pasting of ',' and __VA_ARGS__ is a GNU extension

Output from Terminal to match your **Env** section:

```
$ clang --version
Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin14.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

Using the following code:

```
#define DEBUG
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments"
#import "Macros.h"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

In which Macros.h contains:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define AssLog(condition, message, ...) NSAssert(condition, message, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define AssLog(condition, message, ...) if (!condition) NSLog((@"%@ [Line %d] " message), [NSString stringWithUTF8String:__PRETTY_FUNCTION__], __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this answer is the top result for clang's error:

> Token pasting of ',' and VA_ARGS is a GNU extension

C++20 doesn't require the token pasting operator (`##__VA_ARGS__`) and regular `__VA_ARGS__` will work.

[see example here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Variadic-Macros.html)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works well for this specific issue, but if you are trying to actually kill the warning rather than hiding it, you can compile with `-std=gnu++11` or `-std=gnu++1y` or whatever the relevant gnu compliant standard would be for your code base. I was having this same warning and it took some digging to realize what it was trying to tell me. This is for CLang++ but there should be a GCC equivalent.

Relevant Warning

> Token pasting of ',' and **VA_ARGS** is a GNU extension

Env

```
Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0
Thread model: posix
```